# c# Connecting to database using MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, database-connection

I want to connect to my `SqlDatabase` on VirtualBox. I trying different ways to do it but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

I add a `MySql.Data` and `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`.

```
        MySqlConnection connection;
        string server;
        string database;
        string uid;
        string password;
        string port;
        server = "192.168.1.21";
        port = "3306";
        database = "terminal1";
        uid = "root";
        password = "pass";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "PORT=" + port +         ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";" + "Pooling=false";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);


        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            label1.Text = "NET - OK";
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            //0: Cannot connect to server.
            //1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
            //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                    break;
                case 1042:
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts");
                    break;
                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;
                default:

                        label1.Text = "NET - ERROR";

                    break;
            }

        }
```

Can anyone help?

EDIT:
The program displays the error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts .

Comment: Doesn't work how? Does the `mysql` server accept connections from other hosts than localhost?

Comment: in PHP I can connect by ip so I think server accept connections from other hosts than localhost

Comment: Please... dont use the standard dot net names

Comment: And the catch 1042 isnt the error itself, try this to get the real error:   1 `MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message)`

Comment: I've editted my awnser maybe it can help

Comment: @CKY The MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message) shows the same error text it means "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"

Comment: Are all your properties correct, is the port the same as the server port?

Comment: I got this port number. I do not have access to the server or console.

Comment: but you have the acces to logg in

Comment: with the username and passw

Comment: i have acces to phpmyamin and to server by winSCP.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggeld with this issue myself and this is my sqlclass:

```
namespace Chat
{
    internal class DBConnect
    {
        private MySqlConnection _connection = new MySqlConnection();
        private MySqlConnection _register = new MySqlConnection();
        private MySqlConnection _userdata = new MySqlConnection();
        private string _server;
        private string _database;
        private string _uid;
        private string _password;
        public String MessageRecieved;
        //private string _table = "testconnectie";
        private string _port;
        //private bool succes = false;


        //Constructor
        public DBConnect()
        {
            InitializeChat();
            InitializeRegister();
        }

        //Initialize values
        public void InitializeChat()
        {
            _server = "localhost";
            _port = "3307";
            _database = "test";
            _uid = "root";
            _password = "usbw";


            string connectionString = "Server=" + _server + ";" + "Port=" + _port +";" + "Database=" +
                               _database + ";" + "Uid=" + _uid + ";" + "Pwd=" + _password + ";";

            _connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }

        public void InitializeUserData()
        {
            _server = "localhost";
            _port = "3307";
            _uid = "root";
            _password = "usbw";


            string connectionString = "Server=" + _server + ";" + "Port=" + _port + ";" + "Database=" +
                               _database + ";" + "Uid=" + _uid + ";" + "Pwd=" + _password + ";";

            _connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }

        public void InitializeRegister()
        {
            _server = "localhost";
            _port = "3307";
            _database = "testlogin";
            _uid = "root";
            _password = "usbw";


            string registerString = "Server=" + _server + ";" + "Port=" + _port + ";" + "Database=" +
                               _database + ";" + "Uid=" + _uid + ";" + "Pwd=" + _password + ";";

            _register = new MySqlConnection(registerString);
        }

        public bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                _register.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server");
                        break;

                    case 1042:
                        MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts");
                        break;

                    case 1045:
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password");
                        break;
                }
                return false;

            }

        }

        public void Select()
        {
            string selectquery = "SELECT * FROM testconnectie";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectquery, _connection);

            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            _messagelist.Clear();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                _messagelist.Add(dataReader["time"] + "      ");
                _messagelist.Add(dataReader["text"] + "\r\n");
            }

            dataReader.Close();


            MessageRecieved = _messagelist.ToString(); 

        }

        public void Insert(string textvalue)
        {
            //DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("6/22/2009 07:00:00 AM");

            //dt.ToString("H:mm"); // 7:00 // 24 hour clock

            //var now = DateTime.Now;
            //var minutes = now.Minute;
            //var hour = now.Hour;
            //var time = now;

            string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

            string insertquery = "INSERT INTO testconnectie(time, text) VALUES ('"+time+"','"+textvalue+"')";

            try
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insertquery, _connection);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error(1)" + ex);
            }
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            string updatequery = "UPDATE tabelnaam SET waarde='', waarde'' WHERE waarde=''";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = updatequery;
            cmd.Connection = _connection;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        private void Delete()
        {
            string deletequery = "DELETE FROM tabelnaam WHERE waarde=''";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(deletequery, _connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        public bool CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                _connection.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;

            }

        }


        public void Backup()
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime Time = DateTime.Now;
                int year = Time.Year;
                int month = Time.Month;
                int day = Time.Day;
                int hour = Time.Hour;
                int minute = Time.Minute;
                int second = Time.Second;
                int millisecond = Time.Millisecond;

                //Save file to C:\ with the current date as a filename
                string path;
                path = "C:\\ChatBackup" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day +
            "-" + hour + "-" + minute + "-" + second + "-" + millisecond + ".sql";
                StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path);


                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.FileName = "Database Backup";
                psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                psi.Arguments = string.Format(@"-u{0} -p{1} -h{2} {3}",
            _uid, _password, _server, _database);
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;

                Process process = Process.Start(psi);

                string output;
                output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                file.WriteLine(output);
                process.WaitForExit();
                file.Close();
                process.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error , unable to backup! " + ex);
            }
        }



    }

}
```

Hope this helps it may be a bit big but just use function you need

What you could do is use the setting in the project properties to store all you connection data.

So you could put the serverIp, Port, Database, Uid and password in de setting tab.

You can call them like this: `Properties.Settings.Default.serverIp`

Its a little easier so in the end you could do this:

```
string serverIp = Properties.Setting.Default.serverIp;
string port = Properties.Setting.Default.port;
string username = Properties.Setting.Default.Uid;
```

and so on.

Also maybe try to change `UID` in your connectionstring tyo `Uid`

Also you catch the exception but you dont use it, in this case the default should show to exception so you can understand it. you can do it like this:

```
label1.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use DBLinq to integrate mysql to C#.

Please visit [DBLinq](http://dblinq.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Why do you HAVE to use it? i mean Mysql.Data works pretty good